# route defined with negative lookaround matches the route despite the negative assertion

Tags: php, regex, symfony, symfony4, symfony-routing

We want to open a `DELETE` endpoint that allows calls to all positive integers, but not id 1 (aka element 1 cannot be deleted)

Usually to open an endpoint that allows positive integers I configure the route like this

```
delete_elements:
 path: /elements/{id}
 methods: ["DELETE"]
 controller: app.elements_delete
 requirements:
  id: '\d+'
```

For this case I tried to change the regex to one that does not allow number 1 either

```
delete_elements:
 path: /elements/{id}
 methods: ["DELETE"]
 controller: app.elements_delete
 requirements:
  id: /^(?!(?:1)$)\d+/
```

But when I modify the requirement and I call the endpoint the response is that the endpoint does not exist.

> "No route found for "DELETE /elements/59": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET, PUT)"

What is wrong with that regex? What would be the right way to forbid certain values?

Comment: What is the input for the `/^(?!(?:1)$)\d+/` regex?

Comment: @yivi suggested solution *id: \b1\b|(\d+)* allows 1 to be deleted. So the problems seems no to be on the regex. Using valid regex do not result in the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
    id: '^(?!1/?$)\d+'
```

The problem is that routes are redirected to URLs ending in `/` in Symfony. So your original negative lookahead does not work because it's looking for `1` followed by "end of string" (`$`).

By adding `/?` to the regex you say that the negative lookahead can either be `1$` or `1/$`

Although this would work, again my advise is to handle this at application level, and return a 403 when someone tries to delete something they are not allowed to delete, and not return a 404 which means something different.